# Make a Facebook Like Box responsive

Tags: responsive-design, facebook-like

When we want to insert a [Facebook like box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages), we're given auto-generated code to insert into our website.

Unfortunately, the width of the like box is hard baked into the code:

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/bibandtucker.net.au" data-width="450" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="false" data-width="300" data-header="true" data-stream="true" data-show-border="false"></div>
```

How can I make the Facebook like box responsive, so that it will reduce in width to accommodate content areas less than the hard coded width value?

You can see the problem on [this website](http://www.bibandtucker.net.au/test/).  Watch what happens when you reduce the width of the view port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it fluid by doing this (googled for it):

```
.fb_iframe_widget,
.fb_iframe_widget span,
.fb_iframe_widget span iframe[style] {
    width: 100% !important;
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

You can make it responsive by finding where it starts messing up the layout:

```
@media (max-width:1100px) { 
    .fb_iframe_widget,
    .fb_iframe_widget span,
    .fb_iframe_widget span iframe[style] {
        width: 100% !important;
        min-width: 200px;
    }
}
```

Since it's an iframe that you don't control, you can't style it further.

**Demo: http://jsbin.com/mehil/1**

Answer (score 2):

This no longer works as of 2015 -- facebook has updated their code so that there is a minimum width of 180px.

to get around this you have to use JS.

in this case, .facebook-likebox is the wrapper (which is dynamically being scaled in relation to other elements), and .fb-page is the container for the iframe. the code is cross browser.

here is my code snippit:

```
facebookScale = function () {
    var adjustWidth;
    adjustWidth = $('.facebook-likebox').width() / 180;
    return $('.fb-page').css({
      '-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + adjustWidth + ')',
      '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + adjustWidth + ')',
      'transform': 'scale(' + adjustWidth + ')'
    });
  }

$(function(){
    $(window).on('resize', facebookScale);
  })
```

EDIT: also make sure the following is in your CSS:

```
.fb-page{ 
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
}
```

Edit 2: facebook seems to have updated the widget to now have a min width of 180. so the code has been updated to reflect that. the widget should resize to fit the width of your container otherwise

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="fb-wrap">
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/#"
data-width="100%" data-height="#"
data-show-faces="true" data-stream="false" data-header="false"></div>
</div>

.fb-wrap {
padding-top: 10px; width:90%; margin: 0 auto;}

.fb-like-box, .fb-like-box span, .fb-like-box span iframe[style]
{width:  100% !important; }
```

This works perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

this works for me with show faces true

```
.fb_iframe_widget,.fb_iframe_widget span,.fb_iframe_widget span iframe[style] 

{max-width: 100% !important;}
```